# Calling activity from Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I want call another activity from BroadcastReceiver, but this code below is not calling the activity.
please help me out to find appropriate answer.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent("com.example.alaram.MESG");
        context.startService(newIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to `startActivity` or `startService` ?

Answer (score 1):

The call to startService() starts a Service, not an Activity... as the name suggests.

Try:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```